# RPN with operators other than *,/,+,-

Tags: recursion, postfix-notation

I have a class called `Node`.

```
public Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node primaryNext;
    public Node secondaryNext;
}
```

I have a `Node root = null;` And when the first value is received from the input, it then runs something like this.

```
root = new Node;
root.data = /*input*/ ;
root.primaryNext = null;
root.secondaryNext = null;
```

The next step is adding a new `Node` at the end of the list, by pointing `root.primaryNext` or `root.secondaryNext` to a new `Node` while filling the "pointer" tree by levels. So I need to do something like this:

[GIF of the idea.](http://imgur.com/X2Igg)

I think that this could be done using ||, &&, |, & operators applied to each level of nodes with a recursive method. So:

- How do I operate in C# like the RPN?
- If I can, which would be the best way to do it? I understand recursion pretty well, but I might not do the best possible method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

One command to push a single node onto a stack.

Another command to take the two topmost nodes from the stack, combine them and push the result back on the stack.